# React hooks: Hooks way to show the notification

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a project and I've one requirement, that is to show the notifications.

So I'm using react hooks useEffect to do it.

Below is how I'm trying to do.

```
const showNotification = useSelector(
        state => state.showNotificationInfo
    );

useEffect(() => {
        if (showNotification.message !== null && showNotification.description !== null ) {
            const args = {
                message: showNotification.message,
                description: showNotification.description,
                duration: 0
            };
            notification.open(args);
        }
    }, [showNotification]);
```

Here in the above code I'm fetching the redux's showNotificationInfo value and storing it in the variable called showNotification. By default it will be null.

so whenever showNotification changes except null I want to show the notification.

But my problem here is even if the state is null, it's showing the notification with the null values. I'm not sure where I'm making mistake. Can anyone please suggest me a better way of doing it or correct me if possible.

**EDIT 1:**

redux state

```
const initialState = {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    showNotificationInfo: {
        message: null,
        description: null,
        status: null
    }
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_NOTIFICATION_INFO:
            return {
                ...state,
                showNotificationInfo: {
                    ...state.showNotificationInfo,
                    message: action.payload.title,
                    description: action.payload.message,
                    status: action.payload.status
                }
            };
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Component code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { notification } from "antd";

const ShowNotificationsComponent = () => {
    const showNotification = useSelector(
        state => state.showNotificationInfo
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (showNotification.message !== null && showNotification.description !== null) {
            const args = {
                message: showNotification.message,
                description: showNotification.description,
                duration: 0
            };
            notification.open(args);
        }
    }, [showNotification]);

    return (
        <Fragment></Fragment>
    );
};

export default ShowNotificationsComponent;
```

**EDIT 3 :**

Action creator code

So here what I'm doing is whenever I press a button this action creator will be called and sets the redux state (i.e showNotificationInfo) to null and from the backend side I will get the new notification value and I dispatch the new notification value to the store.

```
export const moveToMyList = () => dispatch => {
    const setMoveToListInfoToNull = {
        message: null,
        description: null,
        status: null
    };

    dispatch({
        type: SET_SHOW_NOTIFICATION_INFO,
        payload: setMoveToListInfoToNull 
    });

    return axios({
        method: "post",
        url: API_URL 
    })
        .then(res => {
            const moveToMyListInfo= {};

            moveToMyListInfo["title"] = res.data.message;
            moveToMyListInfo["message"] = res.data.description;
            moveToMyListInfo["status"] = res.data.status;

            dispatch({
                type: SET_SHOW_NOTIFICATION_INFO,
                payload: moveToMyListInfo
            });
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e.response);
        });
};
```

This notification component I'm using is a child component. Even if parent component re-renders, this notification component (child component) is getting displayed regardless of the redux state.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your store too. You are testing if `showNotification` is not null but looks like it's an object to begin with

Comment: @Dominic I've added the store code in the post. I think somewhere in the component side in the useEffect I'm messing it up. Please correct me if I'm wrong because hooks concept is new to me

Answer (score 0):

`showNotification` is an Object, so you cant just check if it's null (x === null).  You can do `showNotification.message === null`

Comment: I've missed adding that. but here my problem is that when I clear notification I set the redux state  (i.e. showNotificationInfo's message, description, and status) to null. so whenever a new value is set to the notification's message, description, and status. Always a blank notification is shown.

Comment: Try deleting `...state.showNotificationInfo` in your reducer

Comment: I've deleted it. the thing is the notification component that I'm using is a child component. Even if the parent component re-renders the child component is running and displaying the unnecessary notification regardless of the state is null or not. I tried to memoize the component still no luck.

Comment: It would be nice if you could set up the code in codepen

Comment: Actually I've managed to fix it but it is a couple of hardcoding that I had to do. But I don't think it's a good fix. The issue here is that, If my parent component re-renders the redux state for showNotification will not be null. so the condition check for null fails in the child component and shows an unnecessary old notification. So actually what I did in my code is that when my parent component re-renders I set the notification state to null. and this actually worked but I don't think its a good fix.